# FreeMarker file path

Tags: java, jetty, freemarker

I have some problems getting freeMarker to get my root directory. I have tried some answers I found in some other threads but they don't seem to be working. Each time I get a FileNotFound exception.
When I run the project in IDEA it works well but when I package it into a war file and deploy to the server I get exceptions.
As for the war file it is packaged in such a way that the html contents I need to serve lie in the root directry (in the same directory with WEB-INF). I have tried setting the directory for template loading to different values but it returns the same result

This is my code:

```
    public class PageGenerator {
        private static PageGenerator pageGenerator;
        private final Configuration cfg;

        public static PageGenerator instance() {
            if (pageGenerator == null) {
                pageGenerator = new PageGenerator();
            }
            return pageGenerator;
        }

        public String getPage(String filename, Map<String, Object> data) {
            Writer stream = new StringWriter();
            try {
                Template template = cfg.getTemplate(filename);
                template.process(data, stream);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream.toString();
        }

        private PageGenerator() {
            cfg = new Configuration();
            String basedir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            try {
                cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(basedir+"/"));
                System.out.println("\n\n" + "This is the system base directory" + "\n" +basedir+"\n\n");
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `cfg.setServletContextForTemplateLoading(servletContext, null)`. Deployed Web applications might not be exposed as normal directories by the Servlet container.